# Listening for custom uri on Windows phone using cordova

Tags: c#, android, ios, cordova, windows-phone-8

I want my app to listen to the "ms-drive-to" uri scheme so that it is listed as one of the apps which will provide drive/walk directions (Ref : [How to respond to requests for directions for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj851121%28v=vs.105%29.aspx))

Is there out-of-the-box support for listening to such an uri scheme in Cordova for the Windows platform?

I see that it has somewhat similar support for iOS : [Cordova Custom URL Scheme Handling.md](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/blob/master/guides/Cordova%20Custom%20URL%20Scheme%20Handling.md)

This plugin [LaunchMyApp-PhoneGap-Plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/LaunchMyApp-PhoneGap-Plugin)
 provides support for iOS and Android.

But I have not been able to find anything for Windows platform yet. Does something like that exist? Or do I have to write a custom plugin for this task? (or extend the existing one to support Windows too)